# error about jsoup_ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I'm trying a simple crawling with jsoup in eclipse.
I downloaded jsoup jar files(jsoup-1.13.1.jar, jsoup-1.13.1-javadoc.jar, jsoup-1.13.1-sources.jar) also added them in the java build path/libaries
But I get some error messages about jsoup...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
> at square.example.main(example.java:12) 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 1 more

This is my code!

```
package square;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class example{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String articleURL = "http://www.imaeil.com/sub_news/sub_news_view.php?news_id=20000&yy=2015";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(articleURL).get();     //error!
        Elements ele = doc.select("div#_article");          
        String str = ele.text();                           
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bw4D.png)

Comment: Verify in your Run Configuration the jsoup jar is listed as a Dependency under `Classpath Entries`.  Note there are two configurations (run and debug) to verify depending on how you run it.

Comment: wow.. I found my problem.. thankyou so much :D